# Open file at startup from init file

Tags: find-file, server

I like that at start emacs visits a file with my todo list. For long time, this has been accomplished by adding `(find-file "~/my-file.org")` at the end of my configuration file (`.emacs`).
However, I found that after installing a new linux distribution (Ubuntu 22.04) emacs is started by default as a daemon. This is ok with me, but I noticed that now the `find-file` command is ignored.

How can I tell the emacs server to open a file at startup from within the configuration file? If the latter is not good practice, how can I obtain the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `server-after-make-frame-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook (lambda () (find-file "~/my-file.org")))
```